# persisting MVC data to ORM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hibernate, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, orm

Java or dotNet world is rich of open source frameworks and libraries. We all like to use Spring and Hibernate almost everywhere.
Everyone agrees that hibernate is a very handy tool.
What Hibernate can do ? well, Basically - Hibernate can track our domain objects changes and persist only modified data to database, that is it.
Basically, That is everything we want. I want to load some records from database, do some modifications to them, and call transaction.commit(), and all modifications get persisted, instantaneously.
That is excelent, right !

But how about web world ? In web applications database session must be closed.
I cannot load some domain objects and wait for user to do modifications through HTTP, and persist those objects after modifications.

We have to use detached objects or DTO. How it works ?
User makes modifications in HTML browser, spring Mvc automatically thransfers those HTML modifiactions to our customized DTO objects using MVC model binding,
then we do some programming effort to transfer modifications from DTO objects to hibernate domain objects and only then we persist them.
For example - we have a web form that updates Customer address, and another form which updates customer details.
We must have two different business layer methods - UpdateAddress() and UpdateDetails(), both methods must accept some kind of DTO,
one represents address information, the other represents details infprmation.
We also have custom logic that transfers data from those 2 DTO to the domain class 'Customer'.
Yes, of course, instead of DTO objects we could reuse our domain classes. But it does not make it simpler.
In both cases we will still have to implement custom logic that transfer modifications to persistent objects,
I cannot persist detached object rightaway, because usually domain classes have lots and lots of properties representing numerous relations, for ex. Customer has - Orders property. When I update customer address I don't want to update its orders.

Is there a beautifull universal way to mapping modifications from mvc model to domain objects without writing a lot of custom code and without risk of overwriting too many fields ?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: using AutoMapper means that I will have to create custom maps for every Service method, which is actually same effort as using custom code for transfering.

Comment: It's one line of code vs. mapping all item properties manually. If there is an entity that cannot be inferred, then you define the mapping explicitly for that one, but most of the time is a huge time saver.

Comment: It is never one line of code... Either I create multiple custom DTO classes for every service method and map them using 1 line-of-code map.  Or I use domain objects and create maps for every service method, specifiing properties to include and properties to exclude, and nested objects behaviour.  I am just telling you that those maps are not necessary, if mapping behaviour can be determined based on incoming JSON or HTTP POST params. Please, Take a look here - sites.google.com/site/upida4j

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to have a data access layer, which translates into having a repository for each domain object / entity. Furthermore, all repositories share common code so you you naturally have an abstract repository:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<E extends BaseModel> implements Repository<E> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<E> entityClass;

    public AbstractRepository(Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected EntityManager getEM() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    protected TypedQuery<E> createQuery(String jpql) {
        return createQuery(jpql, entityClass);
    }

    protected <T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(String jpql, Class<T> typeClass) {
        return getEM().createQuery(jpql, typeClass);
    }

    @Override
    public E merge(E entity) {
        return getEM().merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E entity) {
        getEM().remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public E findById(long id) {
        return getEM().find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

It's also good practice to have a service layer where you are to create, update and delete  instances of an entity (where you could pass through a DTO to the create and update methods if you so desire).

```
...

@Inject
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

public Customer createCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setEmail(customerDto.getEmail());
    ...
    return customerRepository.merge(customer); 
}

public Customer updateCustomerAddress(Customer customer, String address) {
    customer.setAddress(address);
    return customerRepository.merge(customer);  
}
...
```

So it's up to you how many update methods you want. I would typically group them into common operations such as updating the customer's address, where you would pass the customer Id and the updated address from the front end (probably via ajax) to your controller listening on a specific endpoint. This endpoint is where you would use the repository to find the entity first by Id and then pass it to your service to do the address update for example.

Lastly you need to ensure that the data actually gets persisted, so in Spring you can add the `@Transactional` annotation either to you Spring MVC controller or to your service that does the persisting. I'm not aware of any best practices around this but I prefer adding it to my controllers so that you're always guaranteed to have a transaction no matter what service you are in.

Comment: Hi Markus, this looks correct, but again - it is a lot of custom coding. Data access layer is ok, but there is a possibility to avoid writing custom code related to updating each Customer field.

Comment: Hi Markus, this looks correct, but again - it is a lot of custom coding. Data access layer is ok, but there is a possibility to avoid writing custom code related to updating each Customer field.   Imagine the following - my MVC layer accepts JSON replica of Customer. Only certain fields of Customer are present in JSON, others are missing. I parse the JSON into detached Customer object which keeps track of all assigned fields. Then I pass this detached Customer object to Data layer where it maps (or copies) only the assigned fields to the existing persistent Customer object. And I call Save.

Comment: And instead of JSON it could be HTTP POST parameter list.

Comment: OK I see where you are going with this. Unfortunately I am unaware of any such framework/library/design pattern that will give you this result. That being said, TDD is widely accepted as the way to develop software and a layered architecture is the result of properly written unit tests. So I don't see you getting away without the service layer as the data access layer is purely for accessing (and persisting of course), where your controller simply delegates to the appropriate services.

Comment: Lastly the code that you are looking for would be quite a complex custom service to write, which would not be easy to test or maintain. Which ends up not being a great idea.

Comment: I agree that it would be quite complex. But to me it seems obvious that mapping behaviour can be easily determined based on the incoming JSON or HTTP POST params. Why do I have to create mapping code, if it is allways same behaviour - MAP ALL THAT USER ENTERED !  And by the way, it would never be more complex than deserializers or model binders. Take a look here - sites.google.com/site/upida4j